# SQL get max value

Tags: sql

I have a table called Filter with the following columns:

```
FilterID    ViewID  Rank1
3              3      1
220           94      1
221           94      2
```

I need to get the `FilterID` with a maximum Rank for each `ViewID`.

The result should be:

```
FilterID 
3
221
```

For ViewID 94 Rank1 is 2, hence the value is 221.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question as it isnt very clear what your asking

Comment: You are not asking on update query so title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL (which works on nearly all modern DBMS)

```
select FilterID
from (
  select FilterID, 
         ViewID, 
         Rank1,
         max(Rank1) over (partition by ViewID) as max_rank
  from Filter
) t
where Rank1 = max_rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

In shortcut,

```
 select max(FilterID)
  from Filter
group by ViewID
```